# locate HAL Deamon on 18.10

Tags: services

I learned that hald is running all the time

> HAL Daemon The Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) Daemon, or hald, is a user-space
>   program that runs at all times (that is, as a daemon) and provides other user-space pro-
>   grams with information about available hardware.

However, I cannot find it from daemon running on ubuntu 18.10

```
me@host:~$ ps -aux | grep -i 'daemon' | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
root       862  0.0  0.1 144708  5248 ?        Ssl  08:11   0:01 /usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable
message+   869  0.0  0.1  24000  4500 ?        Ss   08:11   0:06 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --n
root       873  0.0  0.2 542048  8920 ?        Ssl  08:11   0:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
avahi      885  0.0  0.0  18696  2056 ?        Ss   08:11   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [alpha.local]
root       890  0.0  0.1 254768  5768 ?        Ssl  08:11   0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
avahi      962  0.0  0.0  18504    52 ?        S    08:11   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
rtkit     1152  0.0  0.0 163036  2104 ?        SNsl 08:11   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
me   16008  0.4  0.3 265580 14136 ?        SLl  10:44   0:03 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
me   16026  0.2  0.1  23436  6284 ?        Ss   10:44   0:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --
me   16099  0.0  0.0  21632  3868 ?        Ss   10:44   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog --fork --print-pid 5 --print-ad
me   16192  0.0  0.1  21488  3976 ?        S    10:44   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi
me   16240  0.0  0.4 1535104 17308 ?       S<sl 10:44   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
me   16250  0.0  0.2 392860  8092 tty2     Sl   10:44   0:00 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
me   16259  0.0  0.5 237532 21320 tty2     Sl   10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
me   16290  0.0  1.1 608448 43792 ?        SLl  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
me   16358  0.0  0.5 398776 23188 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-power
me   16360  0.0  0.2 274580 10068 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-print-notifications
me   16361  0.0  0.1 391352  5788 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill
me   16365  0.0  0.1 243744  5708 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-screensaver-proxy
me   16366  0.0  0.2 406860  9232 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sharing
me   16371  0.0  0.2 331496  7904 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-smartcard
me   16374  0.0  0.2 280604  8220 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
me   16381  0.0  0.5 385396 23388 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
me   16384  0.0  0.5 315836 22348 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-wacom
me   16391  0.0  0.1 244176  6148 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-a11y-settings
me   16393  0.0  0.5 237076 20876 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-clipboard
me   16400  0.0  0.6 637364 24816 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color
me   16401  0.0  0.3 354064 14464 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-datetime
me   16402  0.0  0.1 322620  7552 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-housekeeping
me   16403  0.0  0.5 387472 21704 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard
me   16408  0.0  0.6 817744 23772 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
me   16410  0.0  0.1 244176  6288 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-mouse
me   16436  0.0  0.3 396112 12588 tty2     Sl+  10:44   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
me   17659  0.0  0.6 591584 25668 ?        Sl   10:45   0:00 /usr/bin/kactivitymanagerd start-daemon
me   18388  0.0  0.0  11932   828 pts/3    S+   10:57   0:00 grep --color=auto -i daemon
```

How could I locate hald ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find HALD because the Hardware Abstraction Layer has been depreciated and is not included in newer versions of Ubuntu.

There was recently a PPA that was used to install HAL on newer versions of Ubuntu (16.04 and older). However, to the best of my knowledge, this PPA is no longer maintained.

sources:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software))

[wiki.debian.org/hal](https://wiki.debian.org/hal)

[launchpad.net/~mjblenner/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-hal](https://launchpad.net/~mjblenner/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-hal)